# Validity of local variable declaration

Tags: bash, functions

Is these valid local variable declarations in a bash script?

```
local  jf=$1  rc="\e[0m"  iq=8  bfcode  frmt    
local  jf=$1  rc="\e[0m"  bfcode  frmt  iq=8
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: No problems were detected.

Comment: `local` can only be used in a function...